# How to Fill DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in DataGridView in c#

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I am able to Fill data in **DataGridViewComboBoxColumn** on **Form_Load Event** there is any best **Event** to fill data in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. i posted my coding. because i.e.., the way i fill the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn on form load.
on FormLoad i written this code. i am getting data from that "dtcnsmbl"(my DataTable) and **cnsmNm** is my **DataGridViewComboBoxColumn** Name. i am assining DisplayMember and ValueMember properties to that one.

```
dtCnsmbl = prchasecls.RtrvcnsmrData();
            cnsmNm.DataSource = dtCnsmbl;
            cnsmNm.DisplayMember = dtCnsmbl.Columns["cnsm_Name"].ToString();
            cnsmNm.ValueMember = dtCnsmbl.Columns["cnsm_Id"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question little bid confusing(I don't see question at all), but if my guess right, then your assigning of `.DisplayMember` and `.ValueMember` are wrong

Instead of assigning value of column, you need to tell a column name of `.DisplayMember` and column name of `.ValueMember`.

Column name must be from your datatable used as `.DataSource`

```
dtCnsmbl = prchasecls.RtrvcnsmrData();
cnsmNm.DataSource = dtCnsmbl;
cnsmNm.DisplayMember = "cnsm_Name";
cnsmNm.ValueMember = "cnsm_Id";
```

Comment: My answer is working fine in Form Load, But it is not work for me at this time. so in EditinControlEvent how to fill Datagridview